# How to avoid implicit conversion of MySQL (Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value)

Tags: mysql

When I execute this query

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE sample_col = 'foo';
```

with this table.

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE test\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sample_col` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+------------+
| id | sample_col |
+----+------------+
|  1 |          0 |
|  2 |          1 |
|  3 |          2 |
+----+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

MySQL automatically convert 'foo' of WHERE clause to zero and I received this warning message.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE sample_col = 'foo';
+----+------------+
| id | sample_col |
+----+------------+
|  1 |          0 |
+----+------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'foo' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I configure MySQL to report this warning as error? (Or how can I stop implicit conversion?)

I've set SQL_MODE as strict but it seems not affect SELECT statement.

```
mysql> SELECT @@SQL_MODE;
+------------------------------------------+
| @@SQL_MODE                               |
+------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Version of MySQL is 5.6.16.

```
mysql> SELECT @@VERSION;
+------------+
| @@VERSION  |
+------------+
| 5.6.16-log |
+------------+
```

**[UPDATE]**

The query `SELECT * FROM test WHERE sample_col = 'foo';` was a bug of my code. And I cannot notice the bug because of implicit conversion.
My purpose is "how to avoid such query" or "how to detect this bug soon". So I want to know the way to stop implicit conversion or way to change error level of this from warning to error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather try casting it explicitly using `CAST` or `CONVERT` function like below and don't count on implicit casting.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE sample_col = cast('foo' as int);

(OR)

SELECT * FROM test WHERE cast(sample_col as varchar) = 'foo';
```

Moreover, there is no point is comparing a `INT` type column with `string` value and AFAIK, there is no such setting present to stop implicit casting. if you really want to result in error rather than converting it to 0 then cast it explicitly; in which case it will error out.

See [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) For more information.

Comment: @kosei, If you have read my answer; have clearly mentioned that there is no such setting present to stop implicit conversion/casting. If you really want to avoid this scenario then use explicite casting. That way it will make sure that if casting fails then throw error which is what you want.

Comment: I've missed 3rd paragraph of your answer. I understood that there is no setting to stop implicit conversion. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to compare an integer to a char datatype. But, if you want to get rid of that problem, type cast the integer column to char type in the select query.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE cast(sample_col as char) = 'foo';
```