# Why are there warnings rather than errors in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, warnings

I have been using MySQL to create a database and sometimes warnings come up rather than errors. An example is when I entered a page of full stops as a value. I do not really understand the point of these are why they appear instead of errors. Surely every incorrect value entered into a database should come up with an error, not just some. Please could somebody explain?

Comment: By what mechanism do you expect the database to identify "a page of full stops" as an incorrect value?

Comment: I just thought it is not right as the value was supposed to be an integer, as I declared it.

Comment: There must be something wrong with it because there was a warning...

Comment: Can you please add (1) the layout of your table and (2) the exact text of the warning message?

Answer (score 0):

If you declared a column to be an integer but are attempting to insert a string, MySQL may perform implicit type conversion and emit an warning. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24947777/818054) for a detailed example.

If you want to treat all warnings as errors, you should try [strict mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict).